# Dynamic checkbox in angular 8

Tags: angular, checkbox, dynamic, angular8

I am working with dynamic checkbox in angular 8... i am getting checkbox names list  form a method that result i set as array.. and i have binded that array in html.. but when i submit ngform it returns null value. i am adding my code here

```
additionalCoverArray: Array<AdditionalCovers> = [];
GetQueryAdditionalCovers() {
    this._getCheckboxvalueService.getCheckBoxValues("GetAdditionalCovers").then(result => {
      this.checkBoxes = result;
      this.additionalCoverArray = this.checkBoxes;
      console.log(this.additionalCoverArray);
    });
  }
in html
div class="additionalcovers-form">
    <form #additionalCoversForm="ngForm" class="col-md-12" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(additionalCoversForm.value)">
      <div class="row" *ngIf="additionalCoverArray">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let objCheckbox of additionalCoverArray; let i=index">
              <input type="checkbox"   [(ngModel)]="objCheckbox.isMandatory" id="{{objCheckbox.displayValue}}" name="{{objCheckbox.displayValue}}" value="{{objCheckbox.displayValue}}" (change)="toggleVisibility($event)">
              <label>{{ objCheckbox.displayValue }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label>No Years</label>
              <select (change)="change($event)" [(ngModel)]="noYearsArray.noYears" name="noYears" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                <option *ngFor="let objNoYears of noYears" [value]="objNoYears.displayValue">{{objNoYears.displayValue}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: what value is coming in console.log(this.additionalCoverArray); ?

Comment: @piyushjain      (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {key: "1", displayValue: "UAE and OMAN", isMandatory: true, isSuccess: true, responseCode: "000"}
1: {key: "2", displayValue: "Off Road Cover", isMandatory: false, isSuccess: true, responseCode: "000"}
2: {key: "3", displayValue: "AAA Card", isMandatory: true, isSuccess: true, responseCode: "000"}
3: {key: "4", displayValue: "NCB No Claims", isMandatory: false, isSuccess: true, responseCode: "000"}
4: {key: "5", displayValue: "Dealer Repair", isMandatory: true, isSuccess: true, responseCode: "000"}
length: 5

Comment: issue is in 'No Years' select box, when i am commenting it, i can get checkbox values on submit.  Can you please share noYearsArray ?

Comment: check this url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-checkbox-form, submit form and check console.

Comment: @piyushjain noyears also come under dynamic array.. there is some mistake i have to change that

Comment: ok..please check then

Comment: @piyushjain i think my submit method have some issues.. still i m not able to submit.. getting null.. onSubmit(additionalCoversForm: NgForm) {
    try {
      this.apiCall.getResponseByPostWithoutToken(this._commonService.submitAdditionalCover, this.additionalCoversForm.value).then(
        result => {
          debugger
          console.log("result ", result);
        },
        err => {
          console.log("err ", err);
        });
      console.log(additionalCoversForm.value);
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

Comment: @piyushjain can you please tell what wrong in this?